# ImportError: cannot import name 'context' from 'tensorflow.python.eager' (unknown location)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-import, importerror

I created virtual environment and installed both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu. After that I installed keras. And then I checked in my conda terminal by importing keras and I was able to import keras in it. However, using jupyter notebook if I try to import keras then it gives me below error.

```
import keras
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-88d96843a926> in <module>
----> 1 import keras

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 from . import losses_utils
      8 from . import metrics_utils

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in <module>
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .load_backend import epsilon
      2 from .load_backend import set_epsilon
      3 from .load_backend import floatx
      4 from .load_backend import set_floatx
      5 from .load_backend import cast_to_floatx

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py in <module>
     88 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     89     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 90     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     91 else:
     92     # Try and load external backend.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in <module>
      4 
      5 import tensorflow as tf
----> 6 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
      7 from tensorflow.python.framework import device as tfdev
      8 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as tf_ops

ImportError: cannot import name 'context' from 'tensorflow.python.eager' (unknown location)
```

Already tried uninstalling and installing keras and tensorflow.
I'm pretty new to programming so I am not sure how to go around it. Tried looking other threads but not helping. Can any one recommend what can I do to resolve it? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Did you installed the dependencies with conda? Like this:

```
 $ conda install -c conda-forge keras

 $ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

 $ conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

If you installed with `pip` they will not work inside your virtual env. Look at your conda dependencies list, to see if the tensorflow and keras are really there using:

```
$ conda list
```

If they are, activate your virtual environment:

```
$ conda activate 'name_of_your_env'
```

And run the jupyter inside that, should be something like that (if your env shows in parenthesis the activation worked, and you are now inside the virtual env):

```
(your_env)$ jupyter notebook
```

Comment: My new environment from scratch is using the python 3.8 and I highly doubt that conda package of keras has some kind of problem with it. When I run $ conda install -c conda-forge keras, it give me error of specification incompatible with my CUDA driver. - Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver: feature:/win-64::__cuda==10.2=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==10.2=0

Comment: Also I check $ conda list .. and I found tensorflow 2.2 and keras 2.4.3 both right there. I can happily import tensorflow and keras in my terminal but gives me error as mentioned in my question when I run them in jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Doing below solved my issue.

So I removed all the packages that were installed via pip and intstalled packages through conda. I had environment issue and created another environment from the scratch and ran below commands.
Create virtual environment:

```
conda create -n <env_name>
```

Install tensorflow-gpu via conda and not pip. If you skip create environment command, type in below as it will scratch off new env and specify python and tensorflow version.

```
conda create -n <env_name> python=3.6 tensorflow-gpu=2.2
```

And then I had to make sure that jupyter notebook is opening with the environment that I want it to open with. For that below code.

```
C:\Users\Adi(Your user here)\Anaconda3\envs\env_name\python.exe -m ipykernel install --user --name <env_name> --display-name "Python (env_name)"
```

When you go to Jupyter notebook, on the top right corner you should see your virtual environment and make sure you select that. And it got resolved like that.